# Bundler uses old Ruby version

Tags: ruby

I am getting this error while trying to execute `bundle install`:

```
Gem::InstallError: rex-core requires Ruby version >= 2.2.0.
An error occurred while installing rex-core (0.1.10), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rex-core -v '0.1.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So although I proceed as instructed and install the missing `rex-core` package, the error persists. Doing a `bundle update` did not help either.

And as additional piece of information :

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

What am I supposed to do to solve this problem please?

Comment: what happens if you `gem install rex-core -v '0.1.10'`

Comment: it says : Successfully installed rex-core-0.1.10

Comment: It looks like your `bundle` command uses a different Ruby than your other commands. Check your `$PATH`. You might also try to install bundler again in your current Ruby with `gem install bundler`.

Comment: This is my $PATH : /home/user/.rbenv/shims:/home/user/.rbenv/bin:/home/user/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/home/user/.rbenv/shims:/home/user/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/.rvm/bin
Do you see anything suspicious please ?